# Got a Cell in a DataGrid with the MousePosition

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid with VM for each cell and I need to get a cell(the VM in the cell), if the mouse is over it for my drag/drop-issue

Is there some way to get the VM where the mouse is over?

Is read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2948824b-7e9a-4bc7-a96e-992b65428131/detecting-mouse-click-location-for-a-datagridviewcell) something about ContextMenuStrip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `CellStyle` in the `DataGrid` to listen to the `DragEnter` event:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType={x:Type DataGridCell}>
        <EventSetter Event="DragEnter" Handler="OnDataGridCellDragEnter" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Then you can access the view model in your code behind:

```
private void OnDataGridCellDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
}
```

Note, the `DragEnter` event is only triggered if you use `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` to initiate your drag and drop action. To do the above for normal mouse movement, you can listen to `MouseOver` instead of `DragEnter`.

Comment: ty, but i found a other way to do it.